# Undo function transaction that is called in another function

Tags: postgresql-10

I used postgres and plpgsql functions for the implementation of the business logic of a web app.

My middleware calls plpgsql – functions. 
These plpgsql – functions call other plpgsql functions which do transactions like updates, inserts, deletes etc.

I added some kind of pseudocode bellow to illustrate the logic.

Let’s assume, sub_function_1 and sub_function_2 are performed without any error. sub_function_3 performs an error and runs into the exception.

Since the transactions of sub_function_1 and sub_function_2 only make sense if sub_function_3 is also performed without an error, I would like to make a rollback for the transaction sub_function_1 and sub_function_2 if sub_function_3 runs into an error.

Is it possible to undo / rollback the transaction of sub_function_1 and sub_function_2 after they are performed successfully in case of sub_function_3 runs into an erro?

```
create or replace function root_function()

begin 

-- do some transactions through performing sub_function_1
perform sub_function_1();

-- do here some other transactions

-- do some transactions through performing sub_function_2
perform sub_function_2();

-- do some transactions through performing sub_function_3
perform sub_function_3();

return 'successful';


exception when others then 

    return 'failed';

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Rollback` in the Exception block in your root_function(). Any error in the third sub function will lead to a `ROLLBACK` that also undoes the first two sub functions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION root_function()
   RETURNS VOID
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
   AS $$

BEGIN 

-- do some transactions through performing sub_function_1
    PERFORM sub_function_1();

-- do here some other transactions

-- do some transactions through performing sub_function_2
    PERFORM sub_function_2();

-- do some transactions through performing sub_function_3
    PERFORM sub_function_3();

RAISE NOTICE 'successful';


EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ROLLBACK;

END;$$;
```